# bool function returning unexpected value

Tags: c++

isValid("23:15") returns 0 when it should return 1

```
bool isValid(string s){
    int pos = s.find(":");
    if(s.length() < 4 || s.length() > 5)
        return false;
    else if(s.length() == 5)
    {
        if(s[0] > 2)
            return false;
    }
    if(s[pos + 1] > 5 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Actual output = 0

Comment: What should `isValid` actually do? If your code is broken, it isn't an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you've confused digits for numbers.

```
if(s[0] > 2)
```

should be

```
if (s[0] > '2')
```

and

```
if(s[pos + 1] > 5 )
```

should be

```
if (s[pos + 1] > '5')
```

You also need to think about what happens if `s` does not contain a colon.

Comment: Oh my god, that's it! That's so embarassing but thanks for your help man:)